# Cypher: how to create multiple relationship dependent by more elements?

Tags: neo4j, relationship

is it possible to create a set of relationship between nodes like this?
[situation in RDBMS DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsdFD.png)

An User can be enabled to a service, a service has a set of accounts which can be used, and a user is related to a set of accounts.

The aim is to find, starting from an user, which set of services are enabled and, for each service, the related account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if you actually need a direct relationship between a `User` and an `Account` (it might be redundant, given that `Service`s also have `Account`s). In this answer, I am going to assume they are not needed.

Given my assumption, here is an example of how you can create your illustrated graph (minus one relationship):

```
CREATE (u:User {id: 123})-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(s:Service)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a:Account);
```

To "find, starting from a user, which set of services are enabled and, for each service, the related account":

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 123})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(s:Service)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a:Account)
RETURN u, s, a;
```

This query will return rows with `User`, `Service`, and `Account` values. The `Service` and `Account` values can be `NULL` if the user has no `Service`s. And the `Account` value can be `NULL` if a `Service` has no `Account`s.